# How do I calculate expected values of a Poisson distributed random variable in Python using Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to calculate an expected value of a function of a Poisson distributed random variable using Scipy.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm

G = poisson(mu=30)
G.dist.expect(func=lambda x:(x+1), lb=0, ub=np.inf, *G.args, **G.kwds)
```

This results in an error:

> File "ipython-input-3-da8a2a80eba8", line 2, in module
>   G.dist.expect(func=lambda x:(x+1), lb=0, ub=np.inf, *G.args, **G.kwds)
>
> TypeError: expect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mu'

If I try the same with a normal random variable

```
F = norm(loc=100,scale=30) 
F.dist.expect(func=lambda x:(x+1), lb=0, ub=np.inf, *F.args, **F.kwds)
```

the code works and returns 101.0029332762359.

How should I correctly define the r.v. G so that I can compute the expectation using any function? I use Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 26 2014, 15:25:14), IPython 2.1.0.

Best Wishes, Johannes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some functions expect positional rather than keyword arguments. `stats.poisson`'s `dist.expect` is a case in point. The error

```
TypeError: expect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mu'
```

is saying that `expect` did not expect a *keyword* argument `mu`. But if you just pass the value of `mu` as a positional argument then you'll find that  `G = stats.poisson(30)` works:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

G = stats.poisson(30)
print(G.dist.expect(lambda x: (x+1), G.args, lb=0, ub=np.inf))
# 31.0
```

---

Also, the `G.args` *must* be passed as the second argument to `expect`. You can see this by looking at the help doc string for `G.dist.expect`:

```
In [14]: help(G.dist.expect)
Help on method expect in module scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure:

expect(self, func=None, args=(), loc=0, lb=None, ub=None, conditional=False) method of scipy.stats._discrete_distns.poisson_gen instance
```

Therefore use

```
G.dist.expect(lambda x: (x+1), G.args, lb=0, ub=np.inf)
```

instead of

```
G.dist.expect(func=lambda x:(x+1), lb=0, ub=np.inf, *G.args, **G.kwds)
```

`G.kwds` is an empty dict, so it does not matter if you want to pass it at the end or not.

Comment: Thanks! Why did in my example above the same code for the normal distribution work, and not for the Poisson?

Comment: First, the API does not guarantee that all distributions can take keyword parameters. Second, the `stats.norm` and `stats.poisson` instances are auto-generated and the arguments that they accept are deduced through introspection of its methods. The `loc` and `scale` parameters are present in every distribution, so they have been conveniently made into keyword arguments. But in general the code used to autogenerate the arguments does not make the other parameters keyword parameters. [The autogeneration code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L617)